# WHERE was the longest D&D 5e game held?

Tags: dnd-5e, history-of-gaming

I have looked everywhere on google, bing, yahoo, and so far found nothing. Can anyone tell me where the longest D&D game was held?

Comment: Hi ThatGuy, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Does the link above answer your question? If not please [edit] your question to clarify what's missing. Thanks for contributing and happy gaming!

Comment: If you are looking for answer strictly related to [tag:dnd-5e] you should use that tag instead of the generic d&d one.

Comment: Also, do you mean longest single session, or longest-running campaign over the course of several sessions? If the latter, is that counted in total hours, number of sessions, overall length of time that the sessions took place over, or what?

Comment: If the OP is specifically talking about D&D 5e then this is in no way a duplicate question.

Comment: @Eternallord66 That clarification was adding once the question already had multiple close votes. It remains closed waiting for OP to clarify exactly what they are asking as per KRyan's comment.